# Proof of $I(X; Y) = H(Y) - H(Y\vert X)$?

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

The definition of [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Relation_to_other_quantities) between two random variables $X \sim p_{X}$ and $Y \sim p_{Y}$ is given as follows:
$$I(X; Y) := D_{\text{KL}}(p_{X, Y} \ \vert\vert \ p_{X}\otimes p_{Y})$$
I would like to prove the identity
$$I(X; Y) = H(Y) - H(Y \mid X).$$

---

**Proof attempt**:

Using the definition of the Kullback-Leibler divergence, the mutual information can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
I(X, Y) &= \mathbb E_{(x, y) \sim p_{(X, Y)}}\left[ \log\frac{p_{(X, Y)}(x, y)}{p_{X}(x)p_{Y}(y)}\right] 
\\[4pt] &= \mathbb E_{(x, y)\sim p_{(X, Y)}}\left[ \log\frac{p_{(X, Y)}(x, y)}{p_{X}(x)}\right] - \mathbb E_{(x, y)\sim p_{(X, Y)}}\left[\log p_{Y}(y)\right]
\\[10pt] &= -H(Y \mid X) - \mathbb E_{(x, y)\sim p_{(X, Y)}}\left[\log p_{Y}(y)\right]
\end{align}
However, in my opinion, the last expression does **not** evaluate to $H(Y)$, since the expectation is taken over the joint PDF.

Is there any mistake I am making? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use the Fubini theorem to break down the last expectation into two integrals, one over $X$ and another over $Y$. Then the integral over $X$ of $p_{X,Y}$ will give you the marginal $p_Y$ and the results follows.

Comment: @Enforce Thank you. Is there a way to explicitly show $\int_{\mathcal X}p_{X, Y}(x, y)dx = p_{Y}(y)$?

Comment: Isn't by definition of the marginal probability?